# Acumatica Code Repository not up to date

Tags: c#, visual-studio, acumatica

**Context** : I need to implement a custom Acumatica Screen for a bank reconciliation feature. I take the source of the screen as a base start to develop my own.

**Problem** : the native/base class (CABankTransactionsMaint.cs) I take insipiration from is not even compiling.

**Possible origin** : It is as if the code between the different classes was not at the same version. The compiled DLL are working so could it be that the code repository contains obsolete versions of the source?

The class CABankTransactionsMaint has the following inner class :

```
public virtual decimal EvaluateMatching(CABankTran aDetail, CABankTranInvoiceMatch aTran, IMatchSettings aSettings)
    {
        return StatementsMatchingProto.EvaluateMatching(this, aDetail, aTran, aSettings);
    }
```

aTran is underlined with following message :

> Impossible Conversion
>   from 'PX.Objects.CA.BankStatementProtoHelpers.CABankTranInvoiceMatch'
>   to 'PX.Objects.CA.CATran'

Indeed in the namespace BankStatementProtoHelpers, the static class StatementsMatchingProto has no method taking CABankTranInvoiceMatch type as arguement.

The page is working on the published acumatica version though (6.10.1219)

How can I have an updated code repository if that is the issue? Or is there another fix to this? (other than guess and write the missing methods if possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StatementsMatchingProto has method which takes CABankTranInvoiceMatch:

```
public static decimal EvaluateMatching(CABankTransactionsMaint graph, CABankTran aDetail, CABankTranInvoiceMatch aTran, IMatchSettings aSettings)
        {
            decimal relevance = Decimal.Zero;
...
```

Comment: Yes actually I had another error that was misleading me and the compiler. I was able to copy the class properly.